# Java : Libgdx button

Tags: java, libgdx

I have created text Button in this way

```
atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("gamebuttons/button.pack"));
    skin = new Skin(atlas);
    stage = new Stage();
    table = new Table(skin);
    table.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("button.up");
    textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("button.down");
    textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetX = 1;
    textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetY = -1;
    textButtonStyle.font = text;
    textButtonStyle.fontColor=Color.BLACK;
    playAgain = new TextButton("PlayAgain", textButtonStyle);
    playAgain.pad(10f);
    table.add(playAgain);
    table.debug();
    stage.addActor(table);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

It works properly , only the text of my button ("PlayAgain") is flipped.How can I flip it on Y axis?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried flipping the loaded TextureRegions, using the flip(boolean x, boolean y) function?

```
 textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("button.up");
 textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("button.down");
```

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html#flip-boolean-boolean-

If that doesn't work, try rotating the cell of the textbutton:

```
playAgain.getLabelCell().getActor().setRotation(180);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't see where you create your text BitmapFont but:

```
 new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("images/font.fnt"), true); // Gives a flipped Font when true
 new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("images/font.fnt"), false); // normal when false
```

maybe you accidentally flipped it.

Another reason why font might be flipped if the font size is negative.